# using coalesce or if results in where clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I use some sql like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(group.display,item.display) as display....
```

I would like to add in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE display='1'
```

WHERE display is the result of the coalesce.

Similarly I'd like to be able to do the same with something like this:

```
IF(ISNULL(gd.group_main_image),p.main_image,gd.group_main_image) AS image
... WHERE image IS NOT NULL
```

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use aliases in the same level of query.

You must repeat yourself.

```
WHERE COALESCE(group.display,item.display) = '1'
```

**EDIT**

Well, I've been too restrictive. You can use alias in an having clause in MySql. You can't do that in other DBMS (Oracle, SQl Server). Generally it's also not permitted in ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **column aliases** in `WHERE` clause

So:

```
WHERE COALESCE(group.display,item.display)='1'
```

OR:

```
HAVING display='1'
```

However, `HAVING` is performed after all the result-set is discovered, so basically this is more memory consuming

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses to refer to the column:
>
> ```
> SELECT SQRT(a*b) AS root FROM tbl_name
>   GROUP BY root HAVING root > 0;
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
>   GROUP BY id HAVING cnt > 0;
> SELECT id AS 'Customer identity' FROM tbl_name;
> ```
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For example, the following query is illegal:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
>   WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
> ```
>
> The `WHERE` clause determines which rows should be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it refers to the alias of a column value that is not known until after the rows have been selected, and grouped by the `GROUP BY`.