# Unknown column inside mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get query with `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.user_type, 
    COALESCE(t2.num_appearences, 0) AS `color`
    FROM user t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT username, process, COUNT(DISTINCT username, process) AS num_appearences
        FROM user_project
        GROUP BY username
    ) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username WHERE `color` IN ('0') GROUP BY username
```

The problem is it gives me error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'color' in 'where clause'` If i try with any other column it works except `color` column. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you selecting `process` in the subquery when you're not using it  anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use allies in where clause, aliases can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Query replace with

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.user_type, 
COALESCE(t2.num_appearences, 0) AS `color`
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT username, process, COUNT(DISTINCT username, process) AS num_appearences
    FROM user_project
    GROUP BY username
) t2
ON t1.username = t2.username GROUP BY username HAVING `color` IN ('0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases in the WHERE clause.

Quoting from [using coalesce or if results in where clause mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326833/using-coalesce-or-if-results-in-where-clause-mysql):

> You must repeat yourself.
>
> `WHERE COALESCE(group.display,item.display) = '1'`